# ASP.net MVC 3 Multi-Select List

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to know how do I get the values from my multi-select list when it has been selected?

I have created the multi-select list by populating it from a database. From there I use HTML Helpers to show the deopdown list on the view.

```
@Html.ListBox("ID", Model.ID)
```

My Question is how can I get the values the user has chosen. This is a multi-select list
Thanks

Also I dont want to have to refresh the page, unless I have to.

Comment: `Also I dont want to have to refresh the page, unless I have to.`: does that mean you want to post back with AJAX?

Comment: @Html.ListBox("ID", Model.ID, new { onchange = "your javascript function here" })

Answer (score 1):

this jquery will solve your problem

```
var values = $("#ID option:selected").text();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This may seems stupid. But I want to be able to return the values to my controller. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use $.ajax method to do this.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the selected Listbox value by setting the property *m => m.SelectedPreference*,

Try this,

`@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedPreference, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { id = "lboxSelectedItems" })`